# AngularJS - change templateUrl if routeprovider starts with certain text

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-routing

I have this code:

```
    var app = angular.module('TabsApplication', ['ngRoute'])
     .config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider
         .when('/search', {
          templateUrl: 'search.html',
          controller: 'SearchController'
        })
        .otherwise({
          redirectTo: '/home'
        });
    }])
```

Right now, I go to http://myapp.com/#/search, it will display search.html. What I want is that if I go to http://myapp.com/#/search?search1=1&search2=2, it will also display search.html.

If I use `'/search*'`, it will redirect to home if I type http://myapp.com/#/search, but if I type http://myapp.com/#/search*, it will show search.html.

Is there a way to do this? I am using AngularJs version 1.2.9.

Comment: Query params should just work with `/search`.

Answer (score 0):

`enter code here`var app = angular.module('TabsApplication', ['ngRoute'])
     .config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider

```
     .when("/search", {
      templateUrl: 'html/somepath/search.html'
      controller: 'SearchController'
    })
    .otherwise({
      redirectTo: '/home'
    });
}])`enter code here`
```

Comment: I recommend you to use absolute path instead of relative path to your templateUrl,